# Play 2 modules: how to add routes without tight coupling?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am developing a [Play 2](http://www.playframework.org/) [module](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Modules) that exposes some URLs and am wondering how I can "offer" these URLs to the Play application that is hosting my module.

**Example:** Suppose my module (called `store`) realizes a document repository, offering (amongst others) the URL `document/<id>` to read the document with id `<id>`. Depending on its needs, the application that uses this module may expose this URL under `http://example.org/media/document/<id>`, or under `http://example.org/document/<id>`, or something else.

**Question:** How does a module expose URLs (routes) to its encompassing application without hardcoding them?

*Note:* I am coming from Django and was looking for a mechanism similar to [Django URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#decoupling-the-urlconfs).

Comment: A tutorial on how to map module routings to a subpath of your top level routing. https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/documentation/manual/Highlights.md#allow-more-modularization-for-your-projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably asking about [HTTP routing](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaRouting)

Note that you need put routing rulez in the main `conf/routes` file. It is supposed to be changed in version `2.1` of the Play.

*Edit:*

check for an example the [sample of SecureSocial](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/samples/java/demo) (there is also Scala version), check how the routes to the module are represented in the [conf/routes](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/samples/java/demo/conf/routes)

Comment: @AdamRabung: by including other routes files: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/12-support-multiple-routes-file-and-inclusion . Of course that doesn't mean that you can't use routes for controllers of modules now, you just need to put them in the main app's routes file.

Comment: @beisior How to redirect to a particular url of securesocial from controller? When I redirect to my application's url, I write routes.MyController.index().absoluteURL(request()). How should I write to call the login of LoginPage controller in securesocial?

Answer (score 3):

This is now supported in 2.1, see section "Allow more modularization for your projects" in the [release notes](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.1-RC4/Highlights). Good news!

Answer (score 2):

If I am not you want to redirect base on certain parameter. Well you can form common controller and they you can you use

```
return redirect(routes.Application.XYZ());
```

to redirect where you want to.